# Application menu shortcut keys underlined, but don't fire in Ubuntu 18.04 with Unity

Tags: 18.04, unity

My environment is Ubuntu 18.04 with Unity as a desktop environment. After launching any GUI application, e.g. LibreOffice Calc or Thunderbird and pressing the ALT key, the application menu is displayed in the window's topbar as expected, and accelerator/shortcut keys in menu entry names become underlined, as shown in the following picture:

[image]

However, pressing any of these accelerator keys, such as "d" for opening the "Datei" menu (German for "File") while keeping the ALT key pressed doesn't have any effect. The expected effect is that this menu should open, but nothing happens at all. This used to work fine in Ubuntu 16.04 and below with Unity. Also, the problem does not exist in Ubuntu 18.04 with GNOME3.

How can I get accelerator keys to work again?